# Inequality $|z_1+z_2|^2 \le (1+|z_1|^2)(1+|z_2|^2)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a problem to prove this inequality 
$|z_1+z_2|^2 \le (1+|z_1|^2)(1+|z_2|^2)$ $\forall (z_1, z_2)\in \mathbb{C}$.

I tried to take the right hand set and subtract the lfs and after simplification I got this:

$1+(ax)^2+(by)^2 -2(ax+by)+(ay)^2+(bx)^2$  and I couldn't prove thqt this result is positive.

Any help please?

Comment: You need the 1 both in $(ax-1)^2$ and in $(by-1)^2$.  Try a square that uses up both $2ax$ and $2by$, and see if $(ay)^2$ and $(bx)^2$ can mop up the remainder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
(1+|z_1|^2)(1+|z_2|^2)=|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+1+|z_1|^2|z_2|^2
$$
Now using AM-GM inequality we have:
$$
1+|z_1|^2|z_2|^2\geq 2|z_1||z_2|
$$
Hence
$$
(1+|z_1|^2)(1+|z_2|^2)\geq |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+ 2|z_1||z_2|= (|z_1|+|z_2|)^2 \ge |z_1+z_2|^2
$$

Answer (score 4):

You can use Cauchy-Schwarz :

$$
|z_1+z_2|^2 \leq (|z_1|+|z_2|)^2 =
(1 \times |z_1|+|z_2| \times 1)^2 \leq (1+|z_1|^2)(1+|z_2|^2).
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
|a+b|^2\le|a|^2+2|a||b|+|b|^2\le|a|^2+ 1+|a|^2|b|^2+|b|^2=(|a|+1)(|b|+1)
$$

Comment: Why is $2|a||b| \le 1 + |a|^2 |b|^2$ ?

Comment: $1-2|a||b|+|a|^2|b|^2=(|a||b|-1)^2\ge 0$

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up.

Answer (score 2):

Put $z_k=r_k(\cos\theta_k+i\sin\theta_k),k=1,2$

$(z_1+z_2)^2=r_1^2+r_2^2+2r_1r_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$

$(1+|z_1|^2)(1+|z_2|^2)=(1+r_1^2)(1+r_2^2)=1+r_1^2+r_2^2+r_1^2r_2^2$

this will be $\ge r_1^2+r_2^2+2r_1r_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$

$\iff 1+r_1^2r_2^2\ge 2r_1r_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$

But $1+r_1^2r_2^2\ge 2r_1r_2$ using AM$\ge$ GM

and $r_1r_2\ge r_1r_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$ as  $\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)\le1$